# Detail view not updating in Split view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail, ipad

Spent a good few hours on this and could not find a solution. I also used this guide to help me:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial

I have a universal app, and in the iPad storyboard i have a Split View controller setup. The problem I'm having is that the detail view is not updating its labels.

Here are some code snippets.

ContactsViewController.h (Master View)

> @property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) ContactsDetailsViewController
>   *contactsDetailsVC;

ContactsViewController.m

```
self.contactsDetailsVC = (ContactsDetailsViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
self.delegate = self.contactsDetailsVC;


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.customTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        id contactsList;
        Contact *aContact;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            selectedRowIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            contactsList = [self.searchedContactsArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
            aContact = contactsList;
        }
        else {
            contactsList = [self.filteredListArray objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.section];
            aContact = (Contact*)[[contactsList contactsList] objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
        }

        if (self.delegate)
            [self.delegate selectedContact:aContact];
}
```

ContactsDetailsViewController.h (Details View)

```
@interface ContactsDetailsViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, ContactSelectionDelegate>
```

ContactsDetailsViewController.m

```
- (void)setContactDetails:(Contact *)aContact
{
    //Make sure you're not setting up the same contact.
    if (_aContact != aContact)
        _aContact = aContact;

    self.name = aContact.name;
    self.department = aContact.department;
    self.email = aContact.email;
    self.skype = aContact.skypeID;
    self.telephone = aContact.telephone;
    self.division = aContact.division;
    self.contactImage = aContact.cachedImage;
}

- (void)selectedContact:(Contact *)newContact
{
    [self setContactDetails:newContact];
}
```

ContactSelectionDelegate.h

```
@class Contact;

@protocol ContactSelectionDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)selectedContact:(Contact *)newContact;

@end
```

Please if someone could point me as to what I'm missing as i really need to solve this, it would be highly appreciated.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Is selectedContact: being called in your delegate?

Comment: Yes the delegate is calling the selectedContact: method successfully! Just the view is not changing. Im still getting empty fields in the labels.

Comment: If you log self.contactsDetailsVC, what does it give you?

Comment: The log gives me <ContactsDetailsViewController: 0xa45dd20> and after when the delegate method gets called i do another NSLog(@"%@",self); in the detail VC and i also get: <ContactsDetailsViewController: 0xa45dd20>. Hence, it does seem like its the correct view that is being updated. Just that the actual updated data is not being displayed. Very weird!

Comment: Do you suggest that i use replace segues in my storyboard to replace my detail view? or is that overkill (as its always the same view just with new data for the labels)?

Comment: No, I wouldn't use those for just new data. As for why your labels aren't updating, I can't see any reason for it. If you can upload the app somewhere where we can download it, or email it to me, I'd be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: ok i tried linking the view to the master view controller via a replace segue and it worked perfectly! Is this the right way to do it though? It seems that any view controller assigned to the detail view of a split view controller just can't update unless you replace it!!! Weird...

Comment: Replace segues are normally used to replace the detail controller with another type of controller, you certainly shouldn't need to use a replace just to update your labels. There's got to be something else going on.

Comment: After rereading your code again, I don't see where you try to update your labels. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: lol silly me, thanks for your help rdelmar. Ive got rid of the replace segues now, i had missed out on actually updating the labels text parameter and was only setting the strings which i had setup for later to copy to the text fields. Thank you.